# Where to add a redirect in my jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a conditional statement that I need to add a redirect depending on what conditional statement is met and I have no clue how to proceed. I am using the jquery.if plugin as well.

```
<div id="load"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// ** DEMO 1 *************
var b1 = "Wholesale";

$("#load")
    .IF(b1 == "Wholesale")
    .html ("window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery';")

    .ELSE()

    .ENDIF()    




</script>
```

Comment: Who's this "wheto" chap?

Comment: This is miraculously ambiguous.  What exactly does this plugin do and what conditions are you trying to meet?

Comment: jQuery IF-Plugin, really?! I don't want to live on this planet anymore.

Comment: I am using http://jquery-if.googlecode.com/ to do basic conditional statements  and am trying to mdify it to add redirects

Comment: That plugin is magical, it will make unicorns appear just from its use.  Oh...who am I kidding?  I know you all love it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to redirect via the clientside.  I'd suggest using plain old vanilla JavaScript via the DOM.

`window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";` should do the trick if all you need is  a redirect.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why you're trying to write logic flow as if they were suddenly jQuery selectors.

```
if (b1 == "Wholesale") {
   $("#load").html("window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery';")
};
```

And do you really want to be writing that script into HTML? Why don't you just run it if you want to perform a redirect?

```
if (b1 == "Wholesale") {
   window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery';
};
```

Comment: (OK, I just found the bit about jQuery.if. But I still don't care.)

Answer (score 0):

The above is really confusing.  That said, jQuery's not going to do much for you in this case.  Also given that you don't really have an else statement to make I don't think you need it.   Here's all you really need to do:

```
if(b1 == "Wholesale") {
  // code to be executed if condition is true
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery");
);
```